# Colour multiple shapes in a sheet based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to write a code for changing the colour of multiple shapes based on a cell value.

I was using a simple approach where if I run the code and the shape name matches the name written in the cell it get's highlighted or else it greys out. I've got shape names by Country (basically shapes named like "China", "Germany", "UK" etc.); the code I'm using is given below:

```
Sub Box_Colour()
Dim Shape_Name As String
Shape_Name = ActiveSheet.Range("N8").Value
        ActiveSheets.Shapes(Shape_Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(237, 125, 49)
        ActiveSheets.Shapes(Shape_Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)

End Sub
```

However I'm getting the error as "Object required"; can you please help me with this?

PS - This currently I'm doing sheet by sheet, however is there any way I can run this code at once for all sheets? Like the shape name is same on every sheet; so value of N8 is "Germany" in Germany sheet, "China" in China sheet. Let me know that as well :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ActiveSheets` should be `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: For your second question, use a loop over all the worksheets.

Comment: Don't forget to add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code so problems like a typo in a name can be caught by the compiler.

Comment: @Bigben Can you help me with the loop please? I'm super new to VBA and have 0 idea about - like on what should I apply the loop? And How? Even a link to this would be helpful :)

Comment: `For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: Just tried it, worked perfectly for the "active sheet" however did not work on the remaining sheet. I believe I'll need to tweak the code a bit or something?

Comment: Change `ActiveSheet` to `ws`.

Comment: It's throwing an error saying "The specified value is our of range"

Comment: Sounds like the value in `N8` on that sheet is not valid maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Looping over sheet and each sheet's `Shapes` collection:

```
Sub Box_Colour()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape, nm As String
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        nm = ws.Range("N8").Value
        For Each shp In ws.Shapes
            shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
               IIf(shp.Name = nm, RGB(237, 125, 49), RGB(166, 166, 166))
        Next shp
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: So this does help as well however this is changing the colour for ALL my shapes; I just need to change the colour for my "country buttons" while for the remaining buttons (this is a different problem) I need to link them to the characters after the sheet name; So basically there are 3 buttons in each country tab; so for those 3 buttons i need them to link on basis characters after underscore; so for "sub-button" in Japan the button should take me to "XYZ_ABC_Japan" and I'm planning to link that to those country names at sheet end (which is also written in cell N8 by the way.

TIA :)